# How to force a libusb event so that libusb_handle_events() returns

Tags: libusb

Suppose I have a libusb program that just uses the hotplug API. You register a callback and then apparently have to call `libusb_handle_events()` in a loop which then calls your hotplug callback.

```
int LIBUSB_CALL hotplugCallback(libusb_context* ctx,
                                libusb_device* device,
                                libusb_hotplug_event event,
                                void* user_data)
{
    cout << "Device plugged in or unplugged";
}

void main()
{
    libusb_init(nullptr);

    libusb_hotplug_register_callback(nullptr,
                                    static_cast<libusb_hotplug_event>(LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_ARRIVED | LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_LEFT),
                                    LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_NO_FLAGS,
                                    LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_MATCH_ANY,
                                    LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_MATCH_ANY,
                                    LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_MATCH_ANY,
                                    &hotplugCallback,
                                    this,
                                    &hotplugCallbackHandle);

    for (;;)
    {
        if (libusb_handle_events_completed(nullptr, nullptr) != LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The question is, *without timeout hacks* how can I exit this event loop cleanly? I can't find any functions that force `libusb_handle_events()` (or `libusb_handle_events_completed()`) to return. In theory they could just never return.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry if this is late.

The question could have been phrased better but I'm assuming (from your comment updates) that your actual program resembles something a little closer to this:

```
int LIBUSB_CALL hotplugCallback(libusb_context *ctx,
                                libusb_device *device,
                                libusb_hotplug_event event,
                                void *user_data) {
    cout << "Device plugged in or unplugged";
}

void SomeClass::someFunction() {
    libusb_init(nullptr);
    libusb_hotplug_register_callback(nullptr,
                                static_cast<libusb_hotplug_event>(LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_ARRIVED | LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_LEFT),
                                LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_NO_FLAGS,
                                LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_MATCH_ANY,
                                LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_MATCH_ANY,
                                LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_MATCH_ANY,
                                &hotplugCallback,
                                this,
                                &hotplugCallbackHandle);

    this->thread = std::thread([this]() {
        while (this->handlingEvents) {
            int error = libusb_handle_events_completed(context, nullptr);
        }
    });
}
```

Let's say your object is being deallocated and, no matter what is happening on the USB bus, you don't care and you want to clean up your thread.

You negate `this->handlingEvents` and you call `thread.join()` and the thread hangs for 60 seconds and then execution resumes.

This is done because the default behavior of `libusb_handle_events_completed` calls `libusb_handle_events_timeout_completed` and passes in a 60 second timeout interval with plans to make it infinite.

**The way you force** `libusb_handle_events_completed` **to return** is you call `libusb_hotplug_deregister_callback` which wakes up `libusb_handle_events()`, causing the function to return.

There is more info about this behavior in the [docs](http://libusbx.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__asyncio.html#asyncevent).

So your destructor (or wherever you want to stop listening immediately) for the class could look something like this:

```
SomeClass::~SomeClass() {
    this->handlingEvents = false;
    libusb_hotplug_deregister_callback(context, hotplugCallbackHandle);
    if (this->thread.joinable()) this->thread.join();

    libusb_exit(this->context);
}
```

Comment: Ah very nice. Better late than never!

Comment: Thanks! Another gotcha that devs might overlook is that the hotplug callback can also be called from [`hotplug_register_callback()`](http://libusbx.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__hotplug.html#gae6c5f1add6cc754005549c7259dc35ea) if you set `HOTPLUG_ENUMERATE`. In this case, deregistering the callback by returning `true` **won't work**, you will need to set the flag you check around your `while` loop and exit early or deregister it manually. I'm not even sure if deregistering it manually inside the callback will work.

Answer (score 0):

In the function:

```
int libusb_handle_events_completed(libusb_context* ctx, int* completed)
```

You can change the value of the completed to "1" so the function will return without blocking

According to their docs:

> If the parameter completed is not NULL then after obtaining the event
>   handling lock this function will return immediately if the integer
>   pointed to is not 0. This allows for race free waiting for the
>   completion of a specific transfer.

Comment: I can't see how that would work unless it keeps polling `*completed`, which is just another timeout hack.

Answer (score 0):

There is no functions in libusb that force `libusb_handle_events()` to return.

It's recommended to use `libusb_handle_events()` in a dedicated thread so your main thread will not be blocked by this call. Even though, if you need to manipulate the call of the event handler you can put the call in a while(condition) and change the condition state in your main thread.

Libusb documentation details this [here](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__asyncio.html).

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer the question at all. `libusb_handle_events()` is already in a dedicated thread (in my actual code). The question is how to exit it cleanly.